# how to fetch data in to parts using JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, urlfetch

My code is working fine with limited data from API to google sheets. But when I try to run same code with large data (like above 10,000 records) it gives error (due to time limit exceed), the solution I am looking for is to get records in parts, 0 to 2000 then 2001 to 4000 and so on till the last record.

Please let me know if anyone can give me some code or idea to do this and make this code working for large records as well.

```
async function pullJSON() {

 var requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    followRedirects: true};

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet7"); // specific sheet name; alternatively use ss.getActiveSheet()

  var url="https://api.covid19api.com/summary"; // Paste your JSON URL here

  var response = await UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,requestOptions); // get feed
  var text = await response.getContentText();
  var text2 = await text.toString();
  var json = await JSON.parse(text2).Countries;
  var dataSet = json;


  var rows = [],
      data;


  for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
    data = dataSet[i];
    rows.push([data.Country, data.TotalConfirmed]); //your JSON entities here
  }

  dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, 2); // last '2' Denotes total number of entites sheet.getR
  dataRange.setValues(rows);

}
```

Comment: Does your API return you the data always in the same order?

Comment: Yes, I have rechecked and its return in same order

Comment: I am surprised that parsing alone takes you long enough to hit the maximum execution time limit, but you can make your request faster by skipping `var text2 = await text.toString();`. This line is not necessary since `text` is already a string.

Comment: I have removed that line but still same issue :(

Comment: "https://api.covid19api.com/summary" takes me 1 second to fetch and parse...From where are you fetching the data? After how much time do you hit the limit?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Now that I understand the problem better, I think I have a solution. First, you fetch the list of countries. Then, you individually query those countries and store their data. Now I see that Google Apps Scripts are limited to 4-5 mins, so this solution could be limited by one of two things, 1) your internet speed and 2) your processing power as Google Apps Scripts run on your machine using the Javascript V8 engine.

So this is what I've come up with. Let me know if it helps. (I developed using node so hopefully I remembered to adjust everything back to your original code)

```js
async function pullJSON() {
  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    followRedirects: true};

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet7"); // specific sheet name; alternatively use ss.getActiveSheet()

  let countriesURL = "https://api.covid19api.com/countries";

  var countriesResponse = await UrlFetchApp.fetch(countriesURL,requestOptions); // get feed
  var countriesText = await countriesResponse.getContentText().toString();
  var countries = await JSON.parse(countriesText);

  for (let i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    var country = countries[i];
    let url = `https://api.covid19api.com/country/${country.Slug}/status/confirmed`;
    var summaryResponse = await UrlFetchApp.fetch(countriesURL,requestOptions); // get feed
    var summaryText = await summaryResponse.getContentText().toString();
    var summary = await JSON.parse(summaryText);

    latestSummary = summary[summary.length - 1]; // Gets only the latest case count
    dataRange = sheet.getRange(2 + i, 1, 1, 2);
    dataRange.setValues([[latestSummary.Country, latestSumary.Cases]]);
  }
}
```

ORIGINAL:

Try something like this:

```js
// after you fetch and parse all the data...
let interval = 2000; // change this to change how many go at once

for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i += interval) {
  let tempRows = rows.slice(i, Math.min(i + interval, rows.length + 1));
  dataRange = sheet.getRange(2 + i * interval, 1, 2 + tempRows.length, 2);
  dataRange.setValues(tempRows);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response but can you put the code where you are mentioning it because I have tried and its not returning anything, thanks

Comment: One more thing to add, the issue is in parsing large data not after that so we have to stop parsing at an interval and then restart from where it stopped after a break.

Comment: So you run into exceeding maximum script execution time at the line `var json = await JSON.parse(text2).Countries;`? Even if you skip the rest of the code?

Comment: @ziganotschka , Yes exactly

Comment: So if the parsing is taking forever, you could retrieve the data in parts, parse individually, and combine them after. You can't split up the string for parsing because it wouldn't be able to determine what you're doing.

Comment: Is it possible you could share your code or how to set it up? I'm not very familiar with Google Apps Scripts.